# I type this code {"name":"upul","email":"upul@gmail.com"} in postman as a post request ,

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman, mysql-workbench

but i got this error,

2021-02-05 12:19:08.944  WARN 8168 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'name' is not present]

**dependencies are,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

** Repository is,**

```
package com.example.sample.springboottest.Model;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }



    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

** Controllers are,**

```
package com.example.sample.springboottest.Controller;

import com.example.sample.springboottest.Model.User;
import com.example.sample.springboottest.Repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/demo")
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@PostMapping(path = "/add")
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email){

    User n =new User();

    n.setName(name);
    n.setEmail(email);
    userRepository.save(n);
    return "Saved";
}


@GetMapping(path = "/all")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUser(){
    return userRepository.findAll();
}




}
```

** Properties are,**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root


spring.jpa.open-in-view=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**Please help me to fix this,**

Comment: What URL did you call? Are you sure you want to catch a query parameter and not a path variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **@ReuestParam** you can't pass **JSON** like what you did.
In order to pass JSON format change @RequestParam to @RequestBody as below:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/add")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser(@RequestBody User user){

//        User n =new User();
//
//        n.setName(name);
//        n.setEmail(email);
//        userRepository.save(n);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "Saved";
    }
```

And postman result would be as below:

[image]

But if you need to use @RequestParam then pass **query string** as below:

```
localhost:8811/demo/add?name=upul&email=upul@gmail.com
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have mixed up `@RequestParam` with `@RequestBody`

You seem to want to `POST` a JSON object to your controller, in which case your method signature should be

`public @ResponseBody String addNewUser(@RequestBody User user){`

Answer (score 0):

```
Required String parameter 'name' is not present
```

Method parameters annotated with `@RequestParam` are required by default. It looks like while you are calling the API, you are not passing the `name` query param.

Edit: In this case, we could be passing the user in the request body.